# How to created a nested function

Tags: python

I defined the following code for "Guess the bird game"

```
print("Hello, welcome to the guess the bird game! You can guess 3 times. GOOD LUCK!")
bird = "robin"

guess_bird = input('First try to guess the bird, please fill in your answer:')

if guess_bird == bird:
    print("Congratulations, you have it right!")

else:
    guess_bird = input("Unfortunately.. Once again, don't give up!"
    if guess_bird == bird:
        print("Congratulations, you have it right!")
    else:
        guess_bird = input("Last try to guess the bird, you can do it!")
        if guess_bird == bird:
            print("Congratulations, you have it right!")

        else:
            print("Sorry, no more tries...")
```

However, I get an error... How can I fix this? The error is:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-787643515908>", line 12
    if guess_bird == bird:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You haven't closed the parentheses on the previous line.

Comment: The title mentions a nested function, yet there doesn't appear to be any in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis `)` on the line `guess_bird = input("Unfortunately.. Once again, don't give up!"`.

Answer (score 0):

`guess_bird = input("Unfortunately.. Once again, don't give up!"` that line should have a closing paren. It is trying to include `if guess_bird == bird:` in the arguments to input.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closed parenthesis.

Where you've written

```
guess_bird = input("Unfortunately.. Once again, don't give up!"
```

it should be written as

```
guess_bird = input("Unfortunately.. Once again, don't give up!") #add the ')' at the end
```

I added a repl.it for reference.

https://repl.it/repls/SugaryUncomfortableComputing